# Importing contacts from outlook csv in php

Tags: php, mysql, outlook, contacts

Hi can some body help me on how can i import contacts from a outlook file.  I assume it's a form of csv file

Comment: If you want an answer you'll have to supply more info than that, as it stands this is a `I can haz teh codez?` question.

Comment: I think different versions of Outlook have exported these in different ways. If you post (part of) the exported file and also define what format you want it converted to, someone might be able to help. You tagged your question "mysql", so even some table description could be helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was allowed export as tab seperated values. Which is a txt file. I used [file-get-contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) with [str-getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse it into a array.

```
str-getcsv(file-get-contents($file), "\t")
```

if you wish to use csv file the use the following

```
str-getcsv(file-get-contents($file), ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should work for a standard CSV(I am not sure if outlook makes any non standard changes to the format

```
$csvLines = file(/path/to/file.csv);
$values = array();
foreach($csvLines as $line)
{
    $fields = explode(',', $line);
    $fieldsTrimmed = array();
    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        $field = trim($field)
        $fieldsTrimmed[] = trim($field, '"');
    }
    $values[] = $fieldsTrimmed;
 }
```

The array values should have all the data with $values[0] showing the field names.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP can directly read CSV files.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)